# Batch-sends based on triggers using TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, schedulebatch, .net

Here is my questions:

Possibility to use a different lists to be associated with the triggered type of sends in Exact target? Every time at least one subscriber has to be associated for the TriggeredSend.

I want to feed all the subscribers in a list. Is it possible to do Batch-sends based on triggers using TriggeredSendDefinition SOAP API?

Comment: Is the batch of subscribers already in the system?  Or will the lists already be populated?

Comment: We will be using the different/new lists each time with these kind of trigger based sends.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, but you're going to need to do it with a different mechanism.  What you should do is set up an automation in Automation Studio.  You can put anything you like in there, File Transfers, Imports, Queries, email send to a list, email send to a data extension, etc.  It would be easiest to set this up using the standard UI for the ET application.  Then, you would start the automation with an API call.

For a code sample on how to start that automation, see http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api/#Perform

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Timothy. Does Automation studio supports detailed Tracking at Event and Subscriber level when using List or Data Extension as a import option for subscribers?

Comment: Yes, but not directly.  You have to think about it as an overlay to automate some of the other ET applications.  So, in your case you would set up everything you want in the Email Application, then go over to automation studio, and put all the email pieces together in an automation.  You would still use the email app for the tracking, just as before.